# comparing usage of inner join and where in

Tags: sql, postgresql

with two tables  - `all_data` and `selected_place_day_hours`

`all_data` has `place_id`, `day`, `hour`, `metric`

`selected_place_day_hours` has fields `place_id`, `day`, `hour`

I need to subset `all_data` such that only records with `place_id`, `day`, `hour` in `selected_place_day_hours` are selected.

I can go two ways about it

**1.Use `inner join`**

```
select a.*
from all_data as a
inner join selected_place_day_hours as b
on (a.place_id = b.place_id)
and ( a.day = b.day)
and ( a.hour = b.hour)
;
```

**2.Use `where in`**

```
select *
 from all_data
 where 
   place_id in (select place_id from selected_place_day_hours)
   and day in (select day from selected_place_day_hours)
   and hour in (select day from selected_place_day_hours)
;
```

I want to get some idea on why, when, if you would choose one over the other from a functional and performance perspective ?

One thought is that in #2 above, probably sub-selects is not performance friendly and also longer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are semantically different.

The `IN` does a *semi-join*, meaning that it returns one from `all_data` regardless of how many rows are matched in `selected_place_day_hours`.

The `JOIN` can return multiple rows.

So, the first piece of advice is to use the version that is correct for what you want to accomplish.

Assuming the data in `select_place_day_hours` guarantees at most one match, then you have an issue with performance.  The first piece of advice is to try both queries on your data and on your system.  However, often `JOIN` is optimized at least as well as `IN`, so that would usually be a safe choice.

Answer (score 1):

These days, SQL tends to ignore what you say and do its own thing.

This is why SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *programming* language: you tell it what you want, not how to do it. The SQL interpreter will work out what you want and devise its own plan for how to get the results.

In this case, the 2 versions will probably produce an identical plan, regardless of how you write it. In any case, the plan chosen will be the most efficient one.

The reasons to prefer the `join` syntax over the older `where` syntax are:

- to look cool: you don’t want anybody catching you with code that is old-fashioned
- the `join` syntax is easy to adapt to outer joins
- the `join` syntax allows you to separate the join part from additional filter by distinguishing between `join` and `where`

The reasons do *not* include whether one is *better*, because the interpreter will handle that.

Answer (score 0):

These are some more notes that are too long for a comment.

First it should be showed that your two queries is different. (Maybe the 2nd query you wrote is a wrong query)

For example:

**all_data**

```
place_id    day     hour    other_cols...
1           4       3       ....
```

**selected_place_day_hours**

```
place_id    day     hour
1           4       9
4444        4444    6
```

Then your **1st** query will get **no row** in return, and your **2nd** will return `(1, 4, 6)`

One more note is that if `(place_id, day, hour)` is unique, your first query is in same purpose of following query

```
SELECT *
FROM all_data
WHERE 
    (place_id, day, hour) IN (
        SELECT place_id, day, hour
        FROM selected_place_day_hours
    );
```

Comment: @wouldn't the `and` take care of this ?

Comment: @user3206440 No. As in example above: `place_id IN (1, 4444) AND day IN (4, 4444) AND hour IN (9, 6)` is not equal to `(place_id, day, hour) IN ((1, 4, 9),(4444, 4444, 6))`